# CakePHP routing for a REST-Service

Tags: rest, cakephp, routes

For the sake of an example i have `user_group`- and a `user`-Model and I would like to build a simple REST-API in Cake.

The structure of the app would be that there is an index-page for the user_groups, where I can do all the CRUD for the group. In the next step I would like to pick a group, see all corresponding users and be able to do all the CRUD things with them as well.

Now for the question: how to build the routes? It is straight forward for the user_groups, but I am not sure how to pass the selected user_group to the user-model (as a GET-param or as a different route (`app/{user_group_name}/user/index`), or ..)

I am using the Router::mapResource function (and Cake 2.5). Note that I am mainly trying out angularjs, so agreed, that the example is not so sophisticated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you simply using query params for that?

```
/users/index?group=14
/users/index?groupName=my-fancy-group
```

Routes will do it as well:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:groupName/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    array('pass' => 'groupName')
);
```

Passing the $groupName as first arg to the action.

Comment: That was my question whether or not that's the way to do it. Thanks!